# Kazakhstan transit visa costs

Tags: visas, transit, us-citizens, kazakhstan, transit-visas

Does anyone have a DEFINITIVE price for a Kazakhstan transit visa for U.S. passport holders? ( at the Kazakh embassy in Tashkent in person)

Comment: [Here is an information](http://www.kazakhembus.com/page/visa-and-consular) on application fees for US passport holders from Kazakh embassy in US. I don't see why it should be different in Toshkent.

Comment: Yea see it says for U.S. passport holders it is $160 for a 5 day transit visa, which is ridiculous of course. I have read 2 other blogs where they say $20 and one says $30..so you see my confusion?

Comment: I believe you should post the links to these blogs. It will help future visitors. Also, link in my previous comment seems to apply only to US embassy. Ministry of Foreign Affairs of Kazakhstan publishes fees for consular operations in different countries. According to this document ([link in kazakh](http://adilet.zan.kz/kaz/docs/V100006372_#z43)) single-entry transit visa in Uzbekistan should cost $20. INAL and also confused which one applies here

Comment: Lots of countries charge very high fees to citizens of countries which impose high fees on their own citizens. So, if the US has high fees for Kazakhstan citizens wanting to visit the USA, it's quite possible that Kazakhstan would say something like "$20 for everyone except Americans, hundreds of dollars just for them"...

Answer (score 1):

Frankly, it may depend on who you are and what officer you get on the day.

It also depends on where you purchase it - it's possible on arrival if you fly in, but not at a land border.

One of the leading resources on the area, Caravanistan, observes that a 5 day transit visa is the standard, and [that the "average" price is US$20](http://caravanistan.com/visa/kazakhstan/transit-visa/).

As the commenters above observed, it varies in different places.  At the embassy in Bishkek it's often rated as easier (When I was there at least) than Tashkent, but things may have changed in two years.

However, despite some travellers' misgivings over the operation of Caravanistan, their information is usually up to date, so I'd take their figure to be as close to accurate as I can find.

Good luck, and enjoy it!